# C# WPF ComboBox.ObjectCollection.IndexOf Method (Object) can't find Object in ComboBox with an other object with the same value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, indexof

I have a Combobox which contain IdDataClass object and im tying to find the index of an IdDataClass in my ComboBox with an IdDataClass with the same parameter as the one in the ComboBox.

```
IdDataClass Instance1 = new IdDataClass(0, "Text");
IdDataClass Instance2 = new IdDataClass(0, "Text");
MyComboBox.Items.Add(Instance1);

int Index = MyComboBox.Items.IndexOf(Instance1);
```

This example will work and will return the index of ContactClientIdDataClass1
But this one

```
IdDataClass Instance1 = new IdDataClass(0, "Text");
IdDataClass Instance2 = new IdDataClass(0, "Text");
MyComboBox.Items.Add(Instance1);

int Index = MyComboBox.Items.IndexOf(Instance2);
```

will not work the value of index is -1. My question is why can't i find the index of instance1 with instance2. They have exactly the same value ?

Ps. I have try to overload the Equals function of my IdDataClass:

```
public class IdDataClass
{
     int _ID;
    string _MyData;

    public IdDataClass(int ID, string Data)
    {
        _ID = ID;
        _MyData = Data;
    }
    public bool Equals(IdDataClass p)
    {
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (_ID == p._ID)&&(_MyData == p._MyData);
    }
}
```

Comment: == will not work the way you want it to. see [How to compare strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc165449.aspx)

Comment: I just test again my Overload function and it's working. It return true if same strings and return false if different

Comment: If one of the answer helped you out please mark it as accepted. If not let us know what didn´t worked as explained so we can improve our answers.

Comment: I know it's because i'm not at home until next wednesday :(  I'm really excited to try your answer because you showed me what i missed:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `IndexOf()` the method uses `Object.Equals()` to determine whether two objects are alike. So your own Equals method never gets called because it is not the same method. You have to override the Equals method to obtain the behaviour you want. Add the following lines:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    IdDataClass otherObject = obj as IdDataClass;
    if (otherObject == null)
        return false;
    else
        return Equals(otherObject );
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return _ID.GetHashCode() + _MyData.GetHashCode();
}
```

Overriding the `GetHashCode()` should be done as well as you never know how the items are stored within a collection. It maybe uses some kind of HashTable for performance manner. You should make clear that instances that are equal (according to your implementation) return the same hash code.

Comment: Thanks a lot that was exactly my problem :) Now it is  working perfectly !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    public class IdDataClass : IEquatable<IdDataClass>
{
    int _ID;
    string _MyData;

    public IdDataClass(int ID, string Data)
    {
        _ID = ID;
        _MyData = Data;
    }

    public bool Equals(IdDataClass p)
    {
        return (_ID == p._ID) && (_MyData == p._MyData);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null || !(obj is IdDataClass))
            return false;
        else
            return Equals(obj as IdDataClass);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return _ID.GetHashCode() ^ _MyData.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a missing line, this is the whole point of my question ! And IdDataClass._ID is the Primary Key of My Contact in a data base and the _MyData is the firsname and lastname of my contact concatenate in a string. I have simplified the code to hide SQL C# complexity

Answer (score 0):

When p is null, this line `if ((object)p == null)` will throw exception, simple p==null is enough.

_ID, and _MyData are private, so you can't access them like in

```
return (_ID == p._ID)&&(_MyData == p._MyData);
```